# How should one implement add_settings_error on custom menu pages?

Tags: plugin-development, errors, validation, settings-api

The [Professional WordPress Plugin Development](http://justintadlock.com/plugindevbook) book explains in detail how to properly use the Settings API, and it also demonstrates how to add Menus and Submenus, but unfortunately it doesn't provide any joined-up examples of this. Whilst I've managed to get most of it working, I can't figure out how to properly implement add_settings_error on custom Menu pages. Here is my code:

```
function settings_main_validate( $input ) {
$valid['text_string'] = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $input['text_string'] );

if ( $valid['text_string'] != $input['text_string'] ) {
    //add_setting_error: $title, $id, $error_message, $class
    add_settings_error( 'fields_main_input', 'texterror', 'Incorrect value entered!', 'error' );
}   

return $valid;
}
```

The validation above will work great on setting rendered using `add_options_page`, but will not display the settings errors on pages rendered with `add_menu_page`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several components to error/notice creation and display process:

1. [`add_settings_error()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error) call to add item to stack (global `$wp_settings_errors` variable).
2. `settings_errors` transient that keeps the errors so they survive move from page to page.
3. [`settings_errors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/settings_errors) function [`get_settings_errors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_settings_errors) to retrieve errors from memory or transient and then displays them.

These work like a charm for Settings API, but unfortunately they aren't setup for generic use. On other hand it is trivial to work around that.

Hook `settings_errors()` to `admin_notices` on your plugin's page, pass the error code to it so it only shows your stuff.

Manually save errors to `settings_errors` transient (just stuff that global variable into it).

Since `get_settings_errors()` expects hint in GET parameters (`$_GET['settings-updated']`) that it should check transient instead of memory you can either provide that or get errors from transient yourself and save them back to global variable before your `settings_errors()` call.

**Update**

You are turning this into bit of a mess with multiple question, so I will try to address your concerns here.

Settings API **does** work with admin pages, that don't use Settings section as base. Your real issue is that in that case error/notice reporting does not work.

First here is what happens when you post form, set up with Settings API:

1. Data gets posted to special `options.php` page.
2. There data gets sanitized/validated using callback.
3. Any error/notices that came up during sanitization/validation are collected and saved in transient.
4. You are redirected back to **wherever you came from**.

Now when you load admin page it checks **if this page belongs to Settings section** and if that case includes tiny `options-head.php` file, that deals with retrieving and displaying errors notices.

So the only thing "not working" on other pages is this latter step, which is trivial to do yourself with overview of related function above (I probably went into too much details on transient, you won't need that for basic case).

Comment: Are you saying the Settings API is not really designed for use in admin menus and screens?

Comment: @trnsfrmr well, it's not my place to say if it was or wasn't **designed**, but it's certainly not **set up** for that natively.

Comment: Damn, I got that completely wrong then. So, the Settings API is merely for screens that live under the Settings menu item? In hindsight that explains why using it on custom menus has been so tricky.

Comment: Seems like a shame that all the cool features of the Settings API are not available to plugins using custom menus.

Comment: @trnsfrmr well you can still try and make use of it, just takes extra effort spent

Comment: I would like to do things the right way, I keep reading about how plugin developers should integrate ( http://wpcandy.com/thinks/custom-admin-screens-are-the-worst ) more carefully with WP, so I'd like to do that if possible. I've posted a new question to understand the rationale behind the Setting API here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23710/why-isnt-the-settings-api-designed-to-work-for-plugins-using-custom-menus

Comment: can you point me to some examples of the hook methods you propose above?

Comment: @trnsfrmr I don't really have complete example to point to... it's just bits and pieces, sometimes you need one part, sometimes another. Here is [basic example of generating notices in my Codex Generator plugin](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/codex-generator/tags/1.1/codex-generator.php#L114).

Comment: Wow! That's technical. I'll re-post my exact code and re-phrase the problem from what I've learn't so far.

Comment: This is a much better question, I think: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23765/how-should-i-be-using-the-settings-api-with-custom-admin-menus-with-reference-to

Comment: That last update nailed it for me! Thanks, Rarst. Whilst I'm still not entirely sure how to get the errors displayed property, if this is the only functionality I guess I can live without it for now. Safe in the knowledge that the rest of the Settings API is working. Perhaps someone will come along with some example code in future...

Comment: How do I call add_settings_error in the sanitization callback and prevent it from saving the form?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I have just been through this. Based on the OP's code, the best solution I found is to insert this code:

```
function your_admin_notices_action() {
    settings_errors( 'fields_main_input' );
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'your_admin_notices_action' );
```

This will add the admin notice display to admin pages rendered using add_menu_page

Answer (score -1):

Simply adding

```
include_once 'options-head.php';
```

to my custom menu page's $function seemed to work fine for displaying the error messages on custom menu pages.