# Why isn't the Settings API designed to work for plugins using custom admin menus?

Tags: plugin-development, menus, settings-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should one implement add_settings_error on custom menu pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/how-should-one-implement-add-settings-error-on-custom-menu-pages)

The Settings API offers all sorts of labour saving features and future proof code. I find it really odd that it's not designed to work with plugins using custom admin menus. Is there any reason  for this? Is the situation likely to change in future?

Comment: You might want to clarify what do you mean by "custom menus".

Comment: Custom admin menus?

Answer (score 1):

The Settings API works just fine on any Admin page; it doesn't care where it is, as long as you tie the settings form to the registered setting, and provide a valid callback function.

Comment: It does? Damn, I'm doing something wrong then. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/how-should-one-implement-add-settings-error-on-custom-menu-pages

Comment: can you explain how to tie the settings form to the registered setting?

Comment: Simple: match the first argument in `register_setting()` to the argument passed to `do_settings_fields()` and to `do_settings_sections()`.

Comment: Oops; make that `settings_fields()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to break the `add_settings_error` functionality.

Comment: But breakage of `add_settings_error()` is not really in the scope of this question, as it is currently written.

Comment: Isn't `add_settings_error` part of the Settings API?